# Permission denied when using bpf_probe_read() in the ebpf program

Tags: c, ebpf, bpf, kprobe

I am unable to read the addr argument and assign it to my struct field.

```
struct accept_args_t {
    struct sockaddr_in *addr;
};


SEC("kprobe/sys_accept")
int syscall__probe_entry_accept(struct pt_regs *ctx, int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen) {
    u64 id  = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    u64 pid = id >> 32;
    if (pid != PID)
        return 0;
    bpf_printk("accept entry called for [PID:%llu]\n", pid);

    struct accept_args_t *accept_args = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&active_accept_args_map, &id);
    if (accept_args) {
        bpf_printk("accept_args_t exists for [ID:%llu]\n", id);
    } else {
        bpf_printk("accept_args_t doesn't exist for [ID:%llu]\n", id);
        struct accept_args_t new_accept_args = {};
        
        u32 size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        bpf_probe_read(new_accept_args.addr, size, addr);  // this line is causing the below error.
        bpf_map_update_elem(&active_accept_args_map, &id, &new_accept_args, BPF_ANY);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`program syscall__probe_entry_accept: load program: permission denied: 0: (bf) r6 = r3: R3 !read_ok (4 line(s) omitted) exit status 1`

Can anyone please tell me how to debug and figure out the root cause of these errors by understanding the error codes just as above, are there any resources where i can find the meaning of these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can retrieve the syscall arguments in that way. Instead, you should be using the dedicated macros:

```c
PT_REGS_PARM3
SEC("kprobe/sys_accept")
int syscall__probe_entry_accept(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
    int sockfd = (int)PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx);
    struct sockaddr *addr = (struct sockaddr *)PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx);
    socklen_t *addrlen = (socklen_t *)PT_REGS_PARM3(ctx);
```

---

**Verifier Error Explanation.** `R3 !read_ok` means register 3 hasn't been initialized and therefore isn't safe to read. It hasn't been initialized because R3 in this case is `addr` which was not correctly declared.

---

**Note.** It's possible you saw BPF programs that are using [bcc](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/) retrieve arguments in that way. That is only possible with bcc because it rewrites the program to a format the kernel understands before loading.

Comment: your BCC insight was vital for me, I was porting a BCC program to libbpf and hit this.     Thanks!